# How to set a webpage as the automatic homepage

Tags: html, css

While uploading a website I made to a domain, I realized that simply putting in the address without any specific paths, the site didn't work. For example, typing in "example.com" leads to the path directory instead of the homepage which would be under something like "example.com/home". How can I set it so that when typing in "example.com" it leads to "example.com/home"? Thanks.

Comment: This entirely depends on your server software that is run. Your server setup is something you would have to share here before we can help.

Comment: If you're using raw code to create your site then `index.php` or `index.html` in your root folder will automatically load when you visit `example.com`. Otherwise you'll need to redirect or [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

***Hi***,

Just make a file name `.htaccess` and put in it this code

`DirectoryIndex homepage.html`

Take care you can't make `.htaccess` file from windows explored

Because it unnamed try to write in notepad and save without name just extension

Finally put it in website root (in hompage.html folder).